# Can Jinja be used inside of a CSS file?

Tags: css, flask, web, jinja2

So I'm using Flask, Python, HTML, CSS, and jinja2 for a project and I wanna try to use jinja to make my website dynamic so I need to ask if it's possible to use jinja inside of my CSS file something like this:

```css
{% if not users.password %}

.login_password_input {
    border-color: red;
}

{{% endfor %}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK nope, you need create classes in css, and call it in your front code

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: You can only write static code in css, but you can create [CSS class](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp) you can call in your html script to recover your custom settings, and then use jinja in the html

Comment: Leave everything what is AFAIK mean

Comment: As far as I know

Comment: also @Devyl how do i actually select my input tag using jinja

Comment: Something like <div class="base {{‘login_password_input’ if not users.password }}">